# Use php variable as src attribute in an HTML image

Tags: php, html, web, src

I'm coding a cart page that checks if there's something in the cart and then, if the condition is true,, it echoes a div with a picture of the product, the amount, the price and the name of the product. The variables are inside a session array because I take the data from other pages (login and sign in) where I declare the following array:

```
$myProdArray=[
  array("Superbiomin", 0.016, 3, "/img/superbiomin.jpg"), //name, units, price, image
  array("Prop P Jaleia Reial", 0.010, 2, "/img/proppjalea.jpg"),
  array("Vitamina C 500mg Mastegable Solaray", 0.0097, 1, "/img/vitc.jpg"),
];
$_SESSION['prods'] = $myProdArray;
```

Everything works but I don't know how to refer to the image name string stored in the session array. Here's the body code of the cart page:

```
<body class="cartbody">
<?php
  $nothing = true;
  for($i = 0; $i<3;$i++){
    if($_SESSION['prods'][$i][2] !== 0) {
      $nothing = false;
      if($nothing == false) {   
    ?>
      <div class="cartbodyfalse">
        <div class="productSummary">
        <?php
          for($j=$i; $j<3;$j++){
            if($_SESSION['prods'][$j][2]>0)echo "
              <div class='indivProdRow'><img src=".
               $_SESSION['prods'][$j][2]." class='prodcartimg'><h5>x" . 
               $_SESSION['prods'][$j][2] . " " . 
               $_SESSION['prods'][$j][0] ." " . 
               $_SESSION['prods'][$j][1] ." ETH</h5></div>";
             }
           }
           echo "</div>";
           $i = $j;       
          }   
        }
        if($nothing == true){
            echo "<div class='cartbodytrue'><div class='cartmsg'><h4 class='nothing'>Sembla que encara no tens res al carret</h4><a href='botiga.php'><button class='btn kbuyin'><i class='fa-solid fa-shop'></i> Seguir comprant</button></a></div></div>";
        } else { ?>
          <div class="ticketactions">
          <?php ?>
          </div>
        <?php } ?> 
        </div>     
    </body>
```

I was expecting the code to output the image, however, it outputs the mini img logo as the src attribute value is incorrect. Finally, apart from the code previously showed, I tried using ".{'session array'}.", and ".'session array'".

Comment: In `<img src=".$_SESSION['prods'][$j][2]."...`? Did you print out `$_SESSION['prods'][$j][2]`? What does it contain?

Comment: `$nothing = false; if($nothing == false) {` is always executed

Comment: Attribute values should be quoted, `src='"`.

Comment: fyi, `<button>` inside `<a>` is invalid

Answer (score 2):

The way I see in your code, the index key for image path is `3`.

Try:

```php
echo "<div class='indivProdRow'><img src='".$_SESSION['prods'][$j][3]."' ...
```

**UPDATE:** You shoud use qoutes/double-qoutes for src as mentioned in comments by @user3783243.

**UPDATE2:** There are too many things wrong with this code, yet another thing is that `"/img/superbiomin.jpg"`is an **absolute** path not **relative**, so this will not show you the image as well, You must use a dot at first of paths to achieve relative path and make it work, use it like: `"./img/proppjalea.jpg"`.

BTW, **irrelevant point** : having PHP tags closed and reopened several times is not a good idea, It may cause more mistakes or even exposing back-end code. Make a buffer of HTML content and flush it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to code like this :‌

```
$myProdArray=[
    [
        "name" => "Superbiomin",
        "units" => 0.016,
        "price" => 3,
        "image" => "/img/superbiomin.jpg"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Prop P Jaleia Reial",
        "units" => 0.010,
        "price" => 2,
        "image" => "/img/proppjalea.jpg"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Vitamina C 500mg Mastegable Solaray",
        "units" => 0.0097,
        "price" => 1,
        "image" => "/img/vitc.jpg"
    ],
];
$_SESSION['prods'] = $myProdArray;
```

Then:

```
<body class="cartbody">
<div class="cartbodyfalse">
    <div class="productSummary">
        <?php
        
        if (count($_SESSION["prods"]) > 0) {
            foreach ($_SESSION['prods'] as $prod) {
                echo "
              <div class='indivProdRow'><img src='" .
                    $prod["image"] . "' class='prodcartimg'><h5>x" .
                    $prod["price"] . " " .
                    $prod["name"] . " " .
                    $prod["units"] . " ETH</h5></div>";
            }
        }
        else{
                echo "<div class='cartbodytrue'><div class='cartmsg'><h4 class='nothing'>Sembla que encara no tens res al carret</h4><a href='botiga.php'><button class='btn kbuyin'><i class='fa-solid fa-shop'></i> Seguir comprant</button></a></div></div>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```